# Users need to edit the document simultaneously

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Does users are able to simultaneous edit the document in O365 team site?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can! It is a feature known as Co-Authoring. What this feature does is it allows multiple people to open a file at once, but it only allows them to edit certain blocks of text. For example, if you and I both open document A with 5 paragraphs of information, we can both have the document open for editing we just cannot edit the same paragraph at the same time.

The link below is a great example of how this works, although its a few years old the idea behind it remains the same.

[Link to youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdAEpQsjQWs).

Comment: The only Limitation, Co - authoring does not work if the document is checked out

Answer (score 1):

Check this video:

[SharePoint - Work together on a document - Simultaneously](https://youtu.be/lbLabdJB31g)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the document simultaneously only if you edit from the browser.

But in the following cases, it can`t be possible.

1. If a file has been opened from the client application. (Opened with MS application on the machine).
2. If a file already opened by client application and other user opened from the browser. You will get `File has been locked with another user` error.
3. A file has been checkout by a user to edit. In this case, other user get an error message like "File Checked out by other and can ben opened in read-only mode".

If a file is being edited by multiple users at a time from the browser you will see following observations.

[image]

- On the ribbon bar, you will observe the list of people name who else editing the file.
- And you will see highlighted cursors in different colors where the user is currently editing (In above screenshot you will find red blinking). But you cannot edit the same portion at a time.